# how to extract the link from xml file and save it as text file in the folder my python file is in

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to extract the links to a text file there are multiple links in the xml

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.something.it/en/new</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <lastmod>2018-01-21</lastmod>
            <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml1 = req.get("https://www.something.it/sitemap.xml")
content = xml1.text
stripped = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', content)

print (stripped)
```

I get this as output in terminal I only need the link nothing else and saved as file.text in same folder that contains my python file

http://www.something.it/en/latest
daily
2018-01-21
0.7

Comment: First google result for "sitemap parser python": https://gist.github.com/chrisguitarguy/1305010

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[xml(ElementTree)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)** to extract the url alone:

Ex:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#content = xml1.text    
content = """<url>
<loc>http://www.something.it/en/new</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <lastmod>2018-01-21</lastmod>
            <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>"""


xmlContent = ET.fromstring(content)
for content in xmlContent.findall('.//loc'):
    print content.text
```

**Result:**

```
http://www.something.it/en/new
```

Comment: how would i get all links from ("https://www.oneblockdown.it/sitemap.xml") here save links as x 
wait 15 seconds save links as Y 
y-x = z 
print z (new product )